# Exchange data php javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have to select a file locally and use it in a python script.

[image]

I can't get the filename in order to have it in my ajax script that i use to call a php function.
This is my javascript, called onclick over Ok button:

```
function myAjax () {
    $.ajax( { type : 'POST',
        data : {},
        url  : 'action.php',              
        success: function ( data ) {
            alert( data );               
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            // executed if something went wrong during call
            if (xhr.status > 0) alert('got error: ' + status); // status 0 - when load is interrupted
        },
        complete: function (data) {
            setImg();
        }
    });
}
```

This is the php script used to call python script:

```
<?
function bb(){
    $out = shell_exec( 'python heatmap.py');
    echo "ok";
    $fp = fopen('log.txt', 'w');
    fwrite

($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
bb();
?>
```

I have to take filename from Browse button and send it to ok button, where the python is called.
What is the correct way to exchange data from input="file" html, javascript and php?

Comment: do you need upload a file via ajax?

Comment: @cmnardi no, i need the filename in order to execute the script with that input file

Comment: So you want to pass the filename from the OS to JS which then passes it to the PHP script, which then calls a python script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm making a lot of assumptions here as the question is not entirely clear...

But presumably you're wanting the name of a file that has been selected from the OS. In JS you can do this using the following.

`var fileName, oForm = document.getElementById('my-file');
    oForm.onchange = function(){
      fileName = this.files[0].name;
    }`

Then in your AJAX call, add the `fileName` variable to your `data` property.

`data : {"filename":fileName},`

And then in your PHP access it via the `$_POST` variable. So...

`echo $_POST['filename'];`